# Change border thickness of specific points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate the first plot below (I apologize for the poor quality; this is a screen shot from a video). Would it be possible to adjust the following code to increase the thickness of the blue borders without increasing the thickness of other borders?

```
x<-0:9
y<-0:9
grid<-expand.grid(x,y)
set<-rep(0,100)
for(i in 1:nrow(grid)){
  if(grid[i,2]<=2 | (grid[i,2]==3 & grid[i,1]<=4) | (grid[i,2]==3 & grid[i,1]>6)| 
     (grid[i,2]==4 & grid[i,1]<=3)|  (grid[i,2]==4 & grid[i,1]>7)|  (grid[i,2]==5 & grid[i,1]<3)){set[i]=1} 
}
set[grid[,1]==5&grid[,2]==5]=2
set[grid[,2]>=6]=3
set[grid[,1]>=6&grid[,2]==5]=3
set[set==0] = 4
set<-as.factor(set)
df<-data.frame(x1=grid[,1],x2=grid[,2],Set=set)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x1, y=x2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Set,shape=Set,size=Set,fill=Set), na.rm=TRUE) +  
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,19,1,21)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red","black","blue"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "red","black","green"))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(5,7,2,5))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank())
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the `stroke` aesthetic. It doesn't come with it's own scale, but you can make one with `scale_discrete_manual()`. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

x<-0:9
y<-0:9
grid<-expand.grid(x,y)
set<-rep(0,100)
for(i in 1:nrow(grid)){
  if(grid[i,2]<=2 | (grid[i,2]==3 & grid[i,1]<=4) | (grid[i,2]==3 & grid[i,1]>6)| 
     (grid[i,2]==4 & grid[i,1]<=3)|  (grid[i,2]==4 & grid[i,1]>7)|  (grid[i,2]==5 & grid[i,1]<3)){set[i]=1} 
}
set[grid[,1]==5&grid[,2]==5]=2
set[grid[,2]>=6]=3
set[grid[,1]>=6&grid[,2]==5]=3
set[set==0] = 4
set<-as.factor(set)
df<-data.frame(x1=grid[,1],x2=grid[,2],Set=set)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x1, y=x2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Set,shape=Set,size=Set,fill=Set, stroke = Set), na.rm=TRUE) +  
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,19,1,21)) + 
  scale_discrete_manual(
    aesthetics = "stroke", 
    values = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red","black","blue"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "red","black","green"))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(5,7,2,5))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>